# combine scalar and vector variables in predictive model

Tags: r, nlp, linear-regression

## reformulation of question

I have variables which are scalars

```
x1 <- 0.3
x2 <- 0.5
```

And variables that are vectors

```
X1 <- list()
X2 <- list()
X1[[1]] <- c(0.2, 0.1, 0.3)
X2[[1]] <- c(0.5, 0.1, 0.8)
X1[[2]] <- c(0.3, 0.9, 0.3)
X2[[2]] <- c(0.3, 0.9, 0.8)
```

I want to build a predictive model to predict a scalar outcome `y`.
Is there a way to keep the vectors intact? The description [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression#Simple_and_multiple_regression) suggests that to be useful:

> The very simplest case of a single scalar predictor variable x and a single scalar response variable y is known as simple linear regression. The extension to multiple and/or vector-valued predictor variables (denoted with a capital X) is known as multiple linear regression, also known as multivariable linear regression. Nearly all real-world regression models involve multiple predictors, and basic descriptions of linear regression are often phrased in terms of the multiple regression model.

Or is that a misinterpretation of my part? Can I just combine everything into a dataframe as variables, without any distinction between variables as scalar and part of a larger vector?

Can i simply `cbind` this like `m <- cbind(x1,x2,X1,X2)` and run a `glm` ? Apparently not, because this:

```
fit <- lm(m[,"X1"]~y)
# invalid type (list) for variable 'm[, "X1"]'
```

Gives an error about the list...

## original formulation of question

I'm a beginner in R, trying to build a predictive model and now want to add wordvectors in addition to scalar values.
I have used `text2vec` (http://text2vec.org/glove.html) to build Global Vectors for wordrepresentation (essentially semantic representations of words in n dimensions). Now I'm trying to include these vectors in my predictive model.

Sample data:

```
# some users
user.id <- c(LETTERS[1:6])  
# that have rated k objects
k1 <- c(0.8, 1.0, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2)
k2 <- c(1.0, 0.6, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 0.6)
k3 <- c(0.2, 0.4, 1.0, 0.8, 0.2, 0.4)

# combined in a dataframe
m <- data.frame(user.id, k1, k2, k3)  
#   user.id     k1     k2     k3
# 1       A    0.8    1.0    0.2
# 2       B    1.0    0.6    0.4
# 3       C    0.2    0.4    1.0
# 4       D    0.2    0.2    0.8
# 5       E    0.4    0.2    0.2
# 6       F    0.2    0.6    0.4

# a predictive model with three categories
pred <- as.data.frame(cbind(c(0.2, 0.2, 0.8, 0.8, 0.4, 0.5), 
                            c(0.8, 0.8, 0.2, 0.1, 0.4, 0.6),
                            c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.9, 0.9)))

rownames(pred) <- user.id
# so user A would fall in categorie V2 with a 0.8 probability
#    V1  V2  V3
# A 0.2 0.8 0.2
# B 0.2 0.8 0.2
# C 0.8 0.2 0.2
# D 0.8 0.1 0.1
# E 0.4 0.4 0.9
# F 0.5 0.6 0.9

# now fit the predictive model with one of the variables
fit.A <- glm(m[, "kFotoA"]~., data = pred)
```

This should give me a model to predict in which of the three categories someone would belong, based on the rating of certain objects.
Now I have a large set of wordvectors (a matrix with 224989 terms in the rows and 50 numeric dimensions in the columns) and I want to add selected wordvectors to the model. A simplified sample of wordvectors with six words (one for every user) and five dimensions:

```
rotterdam <- c(-0.5591611, 0.4638168, -0.6657301, -1.00970, -0.4964429)
haven <- c(-1.4801638, 0.9739170, -0.5680999, -0.68331, 0.3181312)
enneagram <- c(0.443401933, -0.147583544, -0.086073533, 0.004635453, -0.069459528)
zee <- c(-1.0437035, 0.6451703, 0.4914247, -0.8297554, -0.1023576)
oerol <- c(0.3234278, 0.3946120, -0.0951997, -0.2936957, -0.7962330)
uvh <- c(0.9152276, 0.2559245, -0.5879705, 0.7476653, 0.1205143)
glove <- rbind(rotterdam, haven, zee, enneagram, oerol, uvh)
```

I could simply add these wordvectors to the dataframe, but i don't want to split them into scalar and keep them intact as vectors. I don't have a clear idea how to proceed. Maybe i should try to add them with a function like `nest()` from the `tidyr` package and continue with the `glm`? And if so, how would i do that? Or do i need another function like `lm` to combine scalar- and vector-valued variables in a model?

My goal is to let words with a similar semantic structure have a similar impact in the predictive model, like for example the words `rotterdam` and `haven` are 0.73 correlated and should have a more or less comparable impact.

```
library(text2vec)
sim2(glove, method = "cosine")
#            rotterdam       haven        zee  enneagram       oerol        uvh
# rotterdam  1.0000000  0.72923387  0.6174481 -0.3192074  0.50904216 -0.4043373
# haven      0.7292339  1.00000000  0.7734439 -0.8052958 -0.04653973 -0.4590087
# zee        0.6174481  0.77344390  1.0000000 -0.7948741  0.12561740 -0.8107657
# enneagram -0.3192074 -0.80529576 -0.7948741  1.0000000  0.30833610  0.6381868
# oerol      0.5090422 -0.04653973  0.1256174  0.3083361  1.00000000  0.1023369
# uvh       -0.4043373 -0.45900871 -0.8107657  0.6381868  0.10233689  1.0000000
```

Comment: Sorry, but it is hard to understand what are you asking about. Could you please reformulate your question and clarify input? Seems you messed a lot of things together.

Comment: I hoped giving more information would clarify, but it seems to work the other way around :) It comes down to this: i want to correlate variables x with output scalar y, but some of my variables x aren't a simple scalar [x] but a vector X [x,y,z]. How do i build a predictive model that correlates both x and X with y?

Comment: Just `cbind` all variables into single matrix? And I suggest to use matrices for modeling, not data frames.

Comment: i tried reformulating the question. Does `glm` handles a combination of simple scalars and lists?

Comment: and, `glm` requires dataframes, so thats why...